# fjsPDF in Node.js environment loads a black square as opposed to a png image

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, jspdf

I am attempting to generate a pdf file in a node.js environment. I am running node v 14.17.6. The issue I am seeing is that when I attempt to load a png image from the working directory, the image in the pdf is instead just a black square taking up the same space. I've attempted to save the image with transparency removed as I've seen some issues with this.

Note: This is all done in a node.js environment, not in the browser. I've spent over an hour looking for duplicates, but most duplicates seem to be centered on manipulation with the canvas or img element in the browser environment and not all on the server side.

The below code is a massively scaled down reproduction of the issue (all you need is a package.json file with jspdf @ 2.5.1 and an image in the same directory, in this case blue.png)

```
import fs from 'fs';
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';

const file = fs.readFileSync('blue.png');
const fileUri = `data:image/png;base64,${file.toString('base64')}`;

const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [400, 500]);
pdf.addImage(fileUri, 'png', 100, 100, 200, 300);

fs.writeFileSync('test.pdf', pdf.output());
```

package.json is here:

```
{
  "name": "stack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

Updated:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';
import Base64 from 'base-64';
import PNGJS from 'png-js';

const file = fs.readFileSync('blue.png');
console.log(file);
const fileUri = `data:image/png;base64,${file.toString('base64')}`;

global.btoa = Base64.encode; 
global.html2pdf = {};
global.window = {document: {createElementNS: () => {return {}} }};
global.navigator = {};
global.PNG = PNGJS;

const pdf = new jsPDF();
pdf.addImage(fileUri, 'PNG', 40, 20, 0, 0);
fs.writeFileSync('test.pdf', pdf.output());

delete global.btoa;
delete global.PNG;
delete global.window;
delete global.navigator;
delete global.html2pdf;
```

DataUri:
data:image/png;base64,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

Update: The answer was with the writeFileSync function. I used the default encoding (utf-8) by not specifying this parameter. This does not work. Specifying either 'binary' or 'ascii' as in the answer below made this work.

```
fs.writeFileSync('test.pdf', pdf.output(), 'ascii');
```

Comment: I've updated the problems statement with the dataUri that is output from the fileUri variable after assigned. It's a valid URI that parses correctly in an online URI converter. The delete calls run after the write as the write call is synchronous. I deleted the delete calls regardless and I still end up with the same square, so it's not that. I've had bad reads from the file system before, and the program will throw as opposed to render a pdf, but I included the generated URI anyways. JPEG does not work either. Not sure what you mean about valid black and null alpha mask to be honest.

Comment: Back ticks in javascript allow you to evaluate strings with template literals. If I used single quotes the evaluation would be interpreted literally and would not be evaluated. To be clear, what I posted above for the dataUri is what was output from console logging fileUri not anything else. I changed that one line to grab the output, but I didn't change the code above to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've referred to the code provided in the [examples](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/node/Octocat.js) of the jspdf library and its working perfectly fine for me. See below image for code output.

[image]

Adding below the code example here as well for more visibility.

```js
...imports

var Octocat = fs.readFileSync("../images/Octocat.png", { encoding: "latin1" });

var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text("Octocat loves jsPDF", 40, 30, 4);
doc.addImage(Octocat, "test", 10, 40, 180, 180, undefined, "SLOW");

fs.writeFileSync("./Octocat.pdf", doc.output(), "ascii");
```

Please comment if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yeah I agree. I'll give you the points, although I'm not sure you know why my solution was wrong. What fixed my issue was the writeFileSync function call where you specified ascii. Turns out if I use ascii or binary, the file works, if I use utf-8 (default) it doesn't work, nor does it work if I use hex. Weird.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I'm also not sure, you can raise a issue and ask this query on their GitHub page, I also do the same for other libraries.

Comment: Also, please mark it as answer if you feel like it's working, it will help others while looking for their answers.

Comment: Sure thing. I'm probably going to clarify in my initial response as well. I've raised this issue on their GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

You don't neet to use writeFileSync. Just use pdf.save() and it works.

```
import fs from 'fs';
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';

const file =  fs.readFileSync('./cat.png');

const fileUri =  `data:image/png;base64,${file.toString('base64')}`;
console.log(fileUri)
const pdf = new jsPDF();
pdf.addImage(fileUri, 'PNG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
pdf.save("cat.pdf")
```

Comment: That's a good point. I ignored this because the docs say: Saves as PDF document. An alias of jsPDF.output('save', 'filename.pdf'). If you look at the docs for .output, this does not match the signature of that method as described in the alias description, but you are correct this also works in spite of the docs. Thanks. I'll upvote to get you some credit.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
const invoicePdf = doc.output('arraybuffer')
    const docBuffer = Buffer.from(invoicePdf, 'ascii');
    return res.set({
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=invoice for ${customer.name}-${format(new Date(dateReceived),"Pp")}.pdf`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf; charset=ascii'
      }).send(docBuffer)
```